# Duplicated MKAnnotations when charging web service in xCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I make annotations from a response JSON from a Web service.

I can load the pins in the map, but when I move the position of the center I have to reload a new bunch of annotations and delete the old ones. When I do the method it only charges the pins and if I move the center it does the same and recharge.

I've tried a lot of methods like this one...

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in _mapView.annotations) {
    [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

But it only, does this: I gets to the center of the map and when I move the map it returns to the start and I can't zoom  the map cause it reloads and loops.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all annotations, just run this before you add the new ones..

```
 NSMutableArray *toRemove = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:15];
for (id annotation in mapView.annotations){
    if (annotation != mapView.userLocation)
        [toRemove addObject:annotation];

    [mapView removeAnnotations:toRemove];
```